# How to set image in imageView with the help of glide with mipmap or local image?

Tags: android

I got an image view and need to set it with the image from the local storage mipmap with the help of glide?

Comment: local storage mipmap. what's that ??

Comment: see Glide's doc to know how to use it ---\_( - _ - )_/--